# Is Error Recovery Control or TLER necessary for software RAID5 using LVM

Tags: raid, lvm, error-handling

I ave been told that for RAID configurations you don't what to use standard desktop drives because they when/if they enter a error recovery mode they might time out and get dropped from the raid.

Is this true for LVM software RAID or this this a hardware RAID issue primarily?. We are running this server primarily as a backup server and would like to take advantage of the lower price of the desktop drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The whole TLER thing is for stupid hardware raid cards that drop the drive if it does not respond quickly.  Software raid does not suffer from such foolishness.